# What are safe temperature ranges for fermenting miso paste?

Tags: fermentation

I'd like to make some miso paste. The recipes I've seen recommend keeping the miso in a cool, dark place. Unfortunately my house gets hot in summertime and there is no cool place like a cellar or air-conditioned room to store the miso during the summer months.

Does anyone know what are the safe temperature ranges for fermenting miso? How hot is too hot? What happens if miso gets too hot?

- Recipe #1 http://permaculturenews.org/2012/02/04/making-miso/
- Recipe #2 http://japanese-cooking-class-tokyo-mari.com/recipe/2013/11/01/how-to-make-miso-paste-home-made-miso-recipe/

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.soya.be/make-miso.php

"If temperature is too high the koji culture could become inactive."

"The container should be place in a clean room with moderate temperatures (15°C – 25°C)."

Like yeast I think the only danger is that if temperatures get too hot it will stop working or living. Your best bet at keeping it cool is likely putting it in a dark cupboard or somewhere dark with some kind of insulation ideally to stop large temperature fluctuations and stop it getting too hot. You get foil insulated picnic bags for example. Or newspaper or foam would also help insulate.

Comment: Fermentation is an exothermic process, it generates its own heat. I don't know how much that is a factor in miso fermentation, but I'd be careful not trap the heat in the container by insulating it too much.